# Change to a Git branch that already exists

Tags: git

when i type, git branch it shows

```
* master
  restaurentaddtofav
```

I believe im in master branch. I have made some changes. I need to switch to 
**restaurentaddtofav** , so i can commit changes. How do i do that ?

when i do, `git checkout -b restaurentaddtofav`

it says

```
A branch named 'restaurentaddtofav' already exists.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checkout existing remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31223669/checkout-existing-remote-branch)

Comment: Just omit the `-b` to checkout an existing branch rather than (attempt to) create a new one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer to the `git-checkout(1)` manual page:

```
git checkout -b|-B <new_branch> [<start point>]

    Specifying -b causes a new branch to be created as if git-branch(1) were
    called and then checked out. […]
```

So, by explicitly **requesting to create a new branch**, it is correct that you get an error message when that branch already exists.

To **checkout an existing branch**, also see the `git-checkout(1)` manual page:

```
git checkout <branch>

    To prepare for working on <branch>, switch to it by updating the index and
    the files in the working tree, and by pointing HEAD at the branch. […]
```